# fast-rendering array of CALayers vs array of CAShapeLayers in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, calayer, cashapelayer, cgpath

I'm writing an app in which I need to populate 500 or so layers with previously-defined bezier paths and I'm running into either PERFORMANCE or INTERACTIVITY issues depending on which route I choose.  Note that I require no animation features, as the paths i draw are static:

If I use CALayers, drawing the paths to screen takes about 15 seconds (bad), but the resulting interactive experience (i.e moving around the screen) is great.

If I use CAShapeLayers, drawing the paths to screen takes a fraction of a second  (good), but the interactivity is terrible.

This is my code with CALayers:

```
func drawPathToCALayer (myView: UIImageView, pointArray: [CGPoint], bbox: CGRect, color: UIColor) {

// step 1. create path
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
var pathOffset = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( (bbox.origin.x * -1), (bbox.origin.y * -1))
CGPathAddLines(path, &pathOffset, pointArray, pointArray.count)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

// step 2. draw to context -- this is the part that kills the amount of time that we call this function repeatedly

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bbox.size, false, 0)
CGContextAddPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), path)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
CGContextFillPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

// step 3.  assign context drawing to sublayer
let sublayer = CALayer()
let strokeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
sublayer.frame = bbox
sublayer.contents = strokeImage.CGImage

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
myView.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```

This is the code with CAShapeLayers

```
func drawPathToCAShapeLayer (myView: UIImageView, pointArray: [CGPoint], bbox: CGRect, color: UIColor) {

// step 1. create path
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
var pathOffset = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( (bbox.origin.x * -1), (bbox.origin.y * -1))
CGPathAddLines(path, &pathOffset, pointArray, pointArray.count)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

// step 2.  assign path to sublayer
let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()
sublayer.path = path
sublayer.fillColor = color
myView.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```

I like the succinctness and speed of the CAShapeLayer approach, but from an interactivity point of view, this route is a no go.

The question is (thanks for hanging in there), is there is a way to do a hybrid approach in which I draw to a CAShapeLayer temporarily, and use it to populate a CALayer like so?

```
func drawPathToHybrid (myView: UIImageView, pointArray: [CGPoint], bbox: CGRect, color: UIColor) {

// step 1. create path
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
var pathOffset = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( (bbox.origin.x * -1), (bbox.origin.y * -1))
CGPathAddLines(path, &pathOffset, pointArray, pointArray.count)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

// step 2.  assign path to sublayer
let sublayer = CALayer()
let tmplayer = CAShapeLayer()
tmplayer.path = path
tmplayer.fillColor = color
sublayer.contents = tmplayer.contents  // ---> i know this doesn't work, but is there something similar I can take advantage of that doesn't rely on defining a context?
myView.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
```

Or better yet, is there some other way that I can populate an array of CALayers with bezier paths to get both good INTERACTIVITY and PERFORMANCE?

Comment: When are you taking the performance and/or interactivity penalty that's bothersome?  Is it a one time thing when starting the process up, or ongoing as the screen needs refresh?

Comment: You might take a look at SpriteKit which is designed to handle high speed refresh of hundreds of small objects.

Comment: If you’re making hundreds of layers to move around onscreen, you’re going to have performance issues either way. Is there a reason you can’t just draw all the paths into one layer?

Comment: The app I'm building is a drawing app. The reason I don't draw the paths to one layer is that I want to have the ability to 'scrub' backwards or forwards in time so that I can add or remove strokes at will. So, while I don't need to move layers around, I do want the ability to quickly add/delete them and zoom in/out of the view.    With CALayers, I'm able to have about 500 or so layers with no lagging issues.  The problem I'm trying to solve is how to draw them all at once with no perceived delay.  I can do this with CAShape layers, but zooming in and out of view is very laggy.

Comment: Thanks David.  I'll look into spriteKit.  To clarify, the performance hit I'm seeing happens when I try to draw, let's say 500 layers at once. I'm trying to bring that time down to the equivalent of doing the same thing with CAShape layers.  I don't use CAShape layers because, although the screen draw time is great, any interactivity in moving around is pretty bad.